# Can I do Sinatra program without restart server?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

When I modify the code and have to restart server to see results. Have any way out?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a few options, detailed in the [Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading). The simplest appears to be to use `shotgun`, which you can install and invoke as follows:

```
$ sudo gem install shotgun
$ shotgun myapp.rb
```

or if you use define your app by inheriting from `Sinatra::Base` and use a `config.ru` file:

```
$ shotgun config.ru -p 4567
```

Comment: If you execute `shotgun` from your project dir, it will find `config.ru` automatically.

Comment: As a note, shotgun automatically restarts the app. The distinction between automatically taking changes into account, versus restarting the app should be made explicit. +1 though.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Phusion Passenger, you can put this file in the application’s root folder

tmp/always_restart.txt

and it will restart on every request.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html ( section 8.7 )

Comment: The above also works if using 37signal's ``pow`` for OS X and is very convenient during development.(http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.5)

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to use reloader from sinatra-contrib gem (also from [Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading)): First install sinatra-contrib gem, then ensure your application .rb file starts with these lines:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?
```

And then any modified config files will be reloaded (no need to restart server!)

Comment: I don't think this works if you're running Sinatra in modular style... ?